# How to deal with duplicate answers?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a family feud type game but I can't think of any way to deal with duplicate answers. What I mean by this they way the game gets an answer is if any of the answers contains the users inputted answer.

```
ArrayList<Answer> containedAnswers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
    for (Answer a : question.getAnswers())
    {
        if (a.getAnswer().toLowerCase().contains(answer.toLowerCase()))
        {
            containedAnswers.add(a);
        }
    }

    if ((containedAnswers.size() - 1) == containedAnswer)
    {
        containedAnswer = 0;
        containedAnswers.clear();
    }

    for (Answer a : question.getAnswers())
    {
        if (foundAnswers.contains(a))
        {
            continue;
        }

        Answer ans = a;
        if (a.getAnswer().toLowerCase().contains(answer.toLowerCase()))
        {
            if (!containedAnswers.isEmpty())
            {
                ans = containedAnswers.get(containedAnswer);
                containedAnswer++;
            }
```

But then I don't know how to deal with it when more than one answer contains the what the user inputted. For example a question was name another word for *"restaurant"*? And some of the answers are *cafe*, *diner*, and *cafeteria*, so if the user inputs cafe then 2 answers contain cafe, cafe and cafeteria. I tried making an ArrayList of the answers that the inputted word contains but I keep getting an 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'.

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is a bit too broad in its current form.

Comment: If you do a `contains` check, user can just enter "ca" and it will still consider it correct. I believe you need to change it to `equalsIgnoreCase` check instead.

Comment: Well I made it so that the answer has to be at least 3 letters but I still have the problem.